# loud hard drive clicks / noises when working with laptop at an angle (on lap), normal or faulty?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro

Ive just bought a 15" macbook pro, the first thing that i noticed when i got it booted up was a large amount of clicking coming from the hdd. This is when having the laptop at a slight angle on my lap, on a flat surface the clicking is still present but not so loud and not so frequent. (im talking about every 5 seconds or so on my lap)

the hdd it has in it is a: **APPLE HDD HTS547575A9E384**

Is this common ? or just a faulty machine ?

Im thinking of taking it back to the apple store and getting them to just do a straight swap as its less than 24hrs old.

Comment: Does it have a cdrom drive? Is there a cd in it?

Comment: yh its got a cd/dvd drive, but to disc is on it, or has ever been

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HDD is making any abnormal noises of ANY KIND, return it.

Even if the drive isn't faulty, data integrity is too important to take a risk, especially if it is so new.

Comment: yeah, thats what i thinking, im going to take it back

Comment: Do that. Apple is really good at making sure you get a good one. I'm 100% positive they will swap out the drive, run all the quality tests, and give you a brand new warranty on the replaced part. They're cool like that.